# Open Bookmark page from Bookmark Manager on Google Chrome in Mac OS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

I'm trying to find a shortcut that opens a web page from Bookmark Manager on Chrome.
I couldn't find a way that doesn't use the mouse.

I tried <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd>, but this shortcut doesn't open the select page, its open the page bellow.

Version 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit)

Comment: I use the same version, and command + down works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue on version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit). My solution requires a few keystrokes, but you won't have to pick up your mouse. Once the page is highlighted in the Bookmark Manager, copy the link with Cmd+C, open a new tab or window with Cmd+Tab or Cmd+N, paste the copied link with Cmd+V, then hit "Enter" to go to the page.

Comment: Thanks. I will use this until google correct this issue.